# SHA512 linux password in c#

Tags: passwords, sha512

I have password stored in db in the SHA512 linux  hashed format. This is generated using php inbuild function crypto(password, salt) and this hashed string has $6$ in at the beginning.  Now I want to check if this hashed password is correct with respect to user input from c# code.

Though I am trying to generate the hashed password like

```
var sp = SHA512.Create();
byte[] hashedbyte= sp.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pw+salt).ToArray);
return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedbyte);
```

but this gives different output and it does not has $6$ also.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

"$6$" ist Not Just SHA512 plus Salt but denotes an algorithm based in SHA512. It does the hashing several Times in a Loop to deliberately waste time and make brüte force Harder.
Search for source Code of "Linux Crypt" Implementations, for example in Apache Common Codecs (Java).